# Elasticsearch error on Head command

Tags: elasticsearch

When i try to execute this command againt Elasticsearch using sense

```
HEAD /megacorp/employee/1
```

It results in this error:

```
TypeError: dataOrjqXHR is undefined (http://myserver/bundles/sense.bundle.js:23570)
```

While other commands like GET work fine against the same record

Any solution or workaround?

Comment: What happens if you use `curl`? Do you have a proxy inbetween you and your query source.

Comment: Haven't tried with curl , but sense convert the curl to sense syntax automatically. There is no proxy

Comment: Using curl from the command line , no output.

Comment: No, there wouldn't be with a `HEAD` request. You'd need a `-v` in there. But you can compare what you get back from two different docs. This will tell you if it's an elasticsearch problem, or a kibana/sense problem.

Comment: The same problem with HEAD on two different docs

Comment: What are you expecting to get from your `HEAD` request? Because it _should_ just be returning `HTTP` headers, no content.

Comment: It is not returning even headers. And when run inside sense , Why is it giving that error.